# Cannot seem to get the right order of operations

Tags: javascript, html

[image: These are the 3 functions I have for my following site I need to put into javascript.]

I have the right order of operations for the first one I cannot seem to get the right ones for 2 and 3.

Here is my code. https://sstewart4-h44op-2-5.glitch.me

```
 z1 = (x+18)**3 / (y*4);
     z2 = (y+2)(x-4) /(( ( (x)**2)*y)+35);
     z3 = (y**3/10)(x-3) - (4/y)**3;
```

Comment: `(y+2)(x-4)` is not valid JavaScript. Your code has multiple issues that would show up in any developer console.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it the following way:

If you don't want to use the experimental pow function you can use following:

```
z2 = ((y+2)*(x-4)) / ((Math.pow(x, 2) * y) + 35)
z3 = (Math.pow(y ** (3/10))) * (x - 3) - (Math.pow((4 / y), 3))
```

Otherwise you can do it like following:

```
z2 = ((y+2)*(x-4)) / (((x**2) * y) + 35)
z3 = (y ** (3/10)) * (x - 3) - ((4 / y) ** 3)
```

Comment: ** is marked as 'experimental' - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic  You can use Math.pow() instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. For exponent power use [Math.pow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow).Also `(x)**2` seems to be wrong

```
((y+2)*(x-4))/((Math.pow(x,2)*y)+35)
(Math.pow(y,3)/10)*(x-3) -(Math.pow((4/y),3))
```